# Prefetch abort in ARM immediately after LDR

Tags: arm, abort, prefetch

I am facing a system prefetch abort within this code segment. I was facing 2 -3 prefetch abort in the Interrupt service routine.

```
LDR     r1, [r5]         ; Load branch address from vector table and branch
UXTH     r0,r4               ; load vector number as argument to call
BLX     R1
```

On checking the core dump i can see the contents of r5 register is valid and the memory pointed by r5 register is also having valid information i.e the address of a valid information.

Does it could be a effect of keeping uxth instruction. Please suggest

Will this issue be resolved if we keep UXTH above LDR

```
UXTH     r0,r4               ; load vector number as argument to call
LDR     r1, [r5]         ; Load branch address from vector table and branch

BLX     R1
```

Comment: "Prefetch abort occurs when the processor attempts to execute an instruction that has prefetched from an illegal address, that is, an address that the memory management subsystem has determined is inaccessible to the processor in its current mode."

Comment: please provide the machine code and the specific core you are using.

Comment: also the register dump that indicated a specific instruction/address.

Comment: we also need to see the code that preceeds the ldr. at least a few instructions.